# CSS: Spinning letter within Spinning Text?

Tags: css

I have a Codepen with a spinning sentence on hover, "Powered by Coindesk" at the base of the page.

http://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/xOqmpd

I put spans around the letters so I can style them individually.

I want to add another spinner class to the letter P, to get a spinning letter within the spinning text.

```
.spinner:hover {
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count:10;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    cursor:crosshair;
}
```

I can add the blur class to a span, but adding spinner will not change anything. Have I hit the limits of the CSS or is there something I can try that won't be jittery? Thanks.

Comment: P.S. Is it best practice to include lots of code snippets, or just let people read the Codepen?

Comment: How can you hover on letter "p" which is spinning with that speed? Is it just for testing?

Comment: Yes it's tricky Mr Green. Maybe users could hover on the P, which would trigger both the text spin + the individual letter spin at the same time. They would see the P start to move, and the text. I can slow the animation speed right down if I need. I don't know what topic to start Googling, is it nesting?

Comment: The best thing is to use SOs own code embedding, because links expire.

Comment: OK I will do that. But I notice people always link to JSFiddle, so I thought Codepen would be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A span is an inline element, and transforms don't apply to them.

Change the span's display attribute to `inline-block` and it will work.

```
span.spinner {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This works. The single letter actually triggers *after* the main text stops spinning. It looks fine, but I will look for a property where I can trigger events in a set order now. Thanks.